# Difference between loading file and Accessing file using fileReader?

Tags: java, file-io

This looks like a very basic question but still want to ask this as I am not very clear with this concept. I have property file to be accessed from my Java code. 
What is the proper procedure to do that?

1. Should it be loaded (using Property.load) so that it is available to JVM?
2. Or shall I directly access the file using FileReader?

I am not sure are the above 2 same.. Can anyone please put a clear picture on this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: if it is property file case then you should use resourcebundle. that property file you are taking about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about the `Properties` class then you should use the `load()` method. Then you can access the properties using the methods of the class.

If you read the file then you are responsible for parsing the data into a format that allows you to access the properties. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Ok Camickr... What I understood from your answer is that Properties Class already provides the format to read the properties. So it is better to use the load method in-case of Property files. And for non-property files we have to use FileReader for it to be accessible in the user-defined format.

Comment: Yes a FileReader is for regular files.